# I found a new Job, higher salary - Changing Employers under the Germany's Regular work permit

Tags: working-visas, germany, paperwork, blue-card

I work and live in Germany.

I am receiving an offer from another employer in Germany.

I am an IT Specialist, and this offer is within IT Field.

However I don't hold a blue card, because I don't satisfy all requirements.

How should I change employers in this case? Is it just a matter of going to ausladerbehorde(Immigration Office) with a new working contract?

How can I start working while waiting for the approval? If this is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

If your current visa is restricted to your current employer, you have to go to the  immigration office and apply for a new visa. If your visa is not restricted, you can leave your current employer, according to the contract, and start working in the new company.

Comment: What about this link:  https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326856/standort/121885/en/

It says after 2 years here, no problem on that regard... Just change without prior approval...